# Can't see Soft Hyphens on Ubuntu 14.04 when using Eclipse/Sublime Text/etc

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, soft-hyphen

A few days ago I've been suffering a serious issue with a Soft Hyphen hidden in my Java code in a variable name and a column name of the Entity. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and the only way of seeing them was editing this file under Yudit editor. When looking into the same file under Eclipse (luna) or Sublime Text 3, even pasting them on Skype or any other IM I was not able to see this character. (I lost a whole day searching for that hidden "-"). 
However... when a Windows user receives my message on Skype containing Soft Hyphenated text can actually see this freaking character. Copy-pasting the text from a wiki page containing Soft hyphenated text into ANY text editor (notepad, notepad++, Eclipse, InteliJ, even an addres bar of the Web Browser... ) actually make this character visible. 
What is wrong with Ubuntu (or Linux in general?) that not showing it, and ... the most important thing.... how to force Ubuntu to act like a Windows in this case and always show a Soft Hyphenated words.

Example: (I can't see a "-" after "e" here, even when copy and paste it into some text editor): e­mail.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well *I* can't see it there. Have you checked the font being used under Linux?

Comment: But it actually is there. Please copy the "email" text from above and paste it into: http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html
IF you're using Windows please paste it into some text editor.